# Access the collection from a method's view

Tags: backbone.js

I have an issue to access my collection on a view's method, in fact, it works well from the initialize() method, but i created another one (drawVisualization()), and i get an undefined error when i try to access `this.collection`, it's probably a stupid question but i didn't find any solution, i tried to use _.bind on the initialize method but doesn't seem works in this case, here is the code:

```
App.Views.account = Backbone.View.extend({

className: 'account',

el: $('#account-container'),

initialize: function(){
    console.log(this.collection.toJSON()); //Works fine !
    this.template = _.template($('#account-template').html());
    _.bind(this.drawVisualization, this); //Seems to be useless
},

render: function(){
//Some code...
    return this;
},

drawVisualization: function(){
      console.log(this.collection.toJSON()); //Fail because of undefined collection !
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Since it is a model belonging to collection you can actually do this `model.Collection` try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an idea why it doesn't work, but try using underscore's `bindAll`.

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this);  
  this.template = _.template($('#account-template').html());
}
```

For me just dumping `bindAll` in the beginning of each view `initialize` is a good way of avoiding this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

In backbone you don't need to bind `this` to a backbone view's method.

So try skipping this part

`_.bind(this.drawVisualization, this); //Seems to be useless`

and instead bind `this` like this:

```
this.collection.bind("reset", this.drawVisualization, this);
```